# display my own tab using command line tool

Tags: allure

Before creating a new tab report, i have tried to display the example (with attachement tab) provided on [allure-report-plugins repository](https://github.com/baev/allure-report-plugins) .

I have downloaded and upgraded the last [command-line tool](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli/releases/tag/allure-cli-2.4)

I have copied the generated **attachments-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** in the same directory than the allure-cli.jar

I have executed the following command :

java -cp .;**attachments-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** allure-cli.jar generate path/to/xml

I get the a report but i don't find the new tab with attachements.

How to take into account the plugin.jar with command line tool ?  Same question, if i want to use the jenkins plugin to generate report in a CI environnement.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I understand CLI Tool is being migrated to Allure core (it already supports plugins). So, you can:

- use your own patched version (please have a look at `ReportGenerate.java` in Allure Core repository)
- wait for new version (will create pull request ~next week)

Allure plugins support in Jenkins is in progress.

(Already supported in Allure maven plugin.)

Comment: Initially CLI was the part of Allure core. Then we introduced automatic version downloading functionality in CLI and thus it made sense to separate CLI from core because its code wasn't expected to change with each new release. Right now we're migrating to bundles and so far as I can understand it seems to be logical to reintroduce CLI to allure-core because it's also expected to be used in plugins for CI systems.

Comment: @15avr74 PR created (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli/pull/42). You can use patched cli tool in case PR is not accepted (anyway cli tool installation is one-time operation).